# TSQL grouping fields

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, grouping

I have a query that I use to get a count of some fields items:

```
SELECT (SUBSTRING(p.filename,5,9))AS pub,
    
    COUNT(hc.queue)AS Hold,
    COUNT(pff.queue)AS ppf,
    FROM Preflight_Queue p
    
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT status,COUNT(*)AS queue FROM Preflight_Queue WHERE status = 4 GROUP BY status)hc on hc.status= p.status
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT status,COUNT(*)AS queue FROM Preflight_Queue WHERE status = 2 GROUP BY status)pff on pff.status= p.status
    group by SUBSTRING(P.filename,5,9)
```

Which give a record set like this:

```
pub            Hold     pff    
RET-S0313       14      14
ABC-X0313       20      5
```

However in a separate  table (Preflight_Status) I need to get two additional fields.(forecolor and backcolor).

The two tables have relationship based on theses two fields:

preflight_queue.status = preflight_staus.id

SO I attempted the following:

> SELECT (SUBSTRING(p.filename,5,9))AS pub,
>
> ```
> COUNT(hc.queue)AS Hold,(hc.forecolor)as holdfc,(hc.backcolor) AS holdbc,
> COUNT(pff.queue)AS pff,(pff.forecolor)as pfffc,(pff.backcolor) AS pffbc   FROM Preflight_Queue p  LEFT OUTER JOIN (
>                  SELECT p.status,s.forecolor,s.backcolor,COUNT(*)AS queue FROM Preflight_Queue p
>                  JOIN preflight_Status s on s.id = p.status WHERE p.status = 4 
>                  GROUP BY p.status,s.forecolor,s.backcolor
>                  )hc on hc.status= p.status
>  LEFT OUTER JOIN (
>                  SELECT p.status,s.forecolor,s.backcolor,COUNT(*)AS queue FROM Preflight_Queue p
>                  JOIN preflight_Status s on s.id = p.status WHERE p.status = 2 
>                  GROUP BY p.status,s.forecolor,s.backcolor
>                  )pff on pff.status= p.status  group by  SUBSTRING(P.filename,5,9),hc.forecolor,hc.backcolor,pff.forecolor,pff.backcolor
> ```

however since I now have to group the forecolor and backcolor fields. I get this results:

> ```
> pub          Hold     pff    holdfc    holdbc       pfffc         pffbc
>
> RET-S0313     14      14      null       null        null         null
> RET-S0313     null    null   0x000000    0xFF99FF    null         null
> ABC-X0313     20      5       null       null        null         null
> ABC-X0313     null    null    null       null      0x000000     0xFFCCFF
> ```

what I'm looking to do is to have it all on the same row like this:

> ```
> pub          Hold    pff    holdfc       holdbc      pfffc       pffbc
>
> RET-S0313     14      14    0x000000    0xFF99FF    0x000000    0x000000    
> ABC-X0313     20      5     0x000000    0xFF99FF    0x000000    0xFFCCFF
> ```

not sure how to get the one row?

Comment: In your first query, the subquery for hc and pff are identical and they are both joined to p in the same manner -- how do they produce different results?

Comment: My bad it was a type'o thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your first query can be simplified like so:

```
SELECT
SUBSTRING(filename,5,9)AS pub, 
SUM(case when status = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as hold, 
SUM(case when status = 4 then 1 else 0 end) as ppf
FROM preflight_queue
GROUP BY SUBSTRING(filename,5,9)
```

after which, assuming a 1-to-1 relationship between the colors and p.status, your request becomes easier:

```
SELECT 
    SUBSTRING(p.filename,5,9)AS pub, 
    SUM(case when p.status = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as hold, 
    SUM(case when p.status = 4 then 1 else 0 end) as ppf, 
    MAX(case when s.id = 2 then s.forecolor else null end) as holdfc,
    MAX(case when s.id = 2 then s.backcolor else null end) as holdbc,
    MAX(case when s.id = 4 then s.forecolor else null end) as holdfc,
    MAX(case when s.id = 4 then s.backcolor else null end) as holdbc
FROM preflight_queue p
inner join preflight_status s on p.status = s.id
GROUP BY 
    SUBSTRING(filename,5,9)
```

Comment: I decided to take your advice and break out the color into another table.. I don't why I didn't think of that.. thanks.

Comment: mr.Reband, I think I jump to soon, the forecolor and backcolor are in a separate table. the relationship is with the field status in the preflight_queue table so preflight_queue = preflight_Status.status.id

Comment: Ok, I edited my answer.  On closer inspection, I don't think you can get rid of all the case statements unless you go with the alternative approach at the end of my post.

Comment: Thanks but I'm still not there, the results is still not grouping by the pub. what I need is pub,hold_count, pfc_count,hold_forecolor, hold_backcolor,pfc_forecolor,pfc_backcolor,statustype in one row. I might have to rethink my interface at this point.. look at the last example in my post :-)